# Python code to open Jupyter Notebook and point to a specific folder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Python code to open Jupyter Notebook and point to a specific folder

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Normally people show what they've tried so far and ask why it's not working.   Hint, look up the subprocess module and use the command given in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your command prompt/terminal
2. Type `jupyter notebook` and press `Enter`
3. You can use the explorer there to navigate to any folder you want.

For more info, you can go through [this](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html)